# How to correctly re-arrange the code to bypass Rust borrow checker?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn do_something<'a>(map: &'a mut HashMap<u32, Box<u32>>, key: &u32) -> &'a mut u32 {
    if let Some(b) = map.get_mut(key) { return b.as_mut(); }

    let mut b = Box::new(123);
    map.insert(*key, b);

    b.as_mut()
}
```

I have 2 major compiler errors (3rd isn't the case):

- The error with borrowing the `map`
- The error with not implementing the `Copy` trait

I extracted this peace of code from my algorithm, means are the same. Some kind of "translated" code in other languages with GC would compile and run perfectly, but here I'm getting the errors. I understand why these errors occur, but I need my code to work that way: during the iteration I store the node in the map, and use it as the current value in the next iteration. I'm really wondering how to make this code working without some other stuff like `Rc`.

Comment: Use the `entry`-api on the `HashMap` to get an `Entry` for `key` and [`or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.or_insert_with) to insert the newly created `Box` if the `key`-slot had been empty; `or_insert_with` returns a `&mut V`, which is what you want in the second code path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known limitation in the current borrow checker. [Polonius](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2023/10/06/polonius-update.html) should accept this code, whenever it lands (estimates right now are sometime in 2024).

However, the entry-based API is the correct approach anyway. It expresses the same operation much more succinctly, and is accepted by the current borrow checker:

```
fn do_something<'a>(map: &'a mut HashMap<u32, Box<u32>>, key: &u32) -> &'a mut u32 {
    map.entry(*key).or_insert_with(|| Box::new(123)).as_mut()
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6104cd35acb76f18575bf41483f1c4d3))

Comment: Note that Polonius will only accept the first error, not the second. You need to perform a second lookup (`get_mut()`) for it.

Comment: You [don't even need](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=16874f65f89c1dc65e92e7564e9dcae5) the trailing `as_mut()`, the compiler automatically coerces `&mut Box<u32>` to `&mut u32`.

Comment: Not only is the Entry API more succinct, it's only _a single lookup_. `get` + `insert` involve doing the (same) lookup twice in a row: avoiding this performance blunder was the primary motivation for the introduction of the Entry API.